# How to execute a method asynchronously in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Is it possible to call a method asynchronously/parallelly in an MVC3 Action method ?

```
public ActionResult CreateUser(string name,string password)
{
 int newUserId=  myRepositary.CreateUser(name,password)
 if(newUserID>0)
 {
   //i want to execute this asycn /parallel ?
   UpdateUserIDINRelatedTables();
 }
 return RedirectToAction("AccountCreated");
}
public void UpdateUserIDINRelatedTables()
{
  //I will  update the userId in few another tables.

}
```

`UpdateUserIDINRelatedTables` does some backend job to associate the new USERID to soemeother tables. I want to redirect to the `AccountCreated` View as soon as i execute the CreateUser method (do not want to wait till `UpdateUserIDInRelatedTables()` method finishes executing. Any thoughts ? (in C# 4, MVC3)

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using? 3.5 or 4?

Comment: I don't believe there are any multi-threading options you can use, however you can use JQuery to asynchronously call a method. However I'm not sure this helps you here.

Comment: i thing it will work fine, but the success response `AccountCreated` is too early, why do you so sure if there will be no error occur on `UpdateUserIDINRelatedTables` method?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904115/handling-async-request-in-asp-net-mvc/9904394#9904394

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie: I am looking for a server side solution like async. Not javascript

Answer (score 0):

try Asynchronous Controller .
This may help you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx